# how to apply fstab setting in puppet

Tags: linux, puppet, puppetmaster

I am learning puppet, and I was supposed to enact this security measure on mount point `/tmp`:

`/tmp /var/tmp none rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,bind 0 0`

I looked at fstab, and I see this:
`/tmp /var/tmp none bind 0 0`

I have approximately 500 servers to enable this on.  Is there a way to do this on puppet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to edit an existing file and make changes / replacements to lines with Puppet the usual method is to use Augeas. For details on how to do so see [Using the Augeas Resource Type](https://docs.puppet.com/guides/augeas.html) in the Puppet documentation.

Comment: In this specific case i think a mount resource type is fittier? Here's the official documentation: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/mount.html

Comment: This is the /tmp folder.  Can a Mount work that?  if not, what I need to do in fstab is update a line, not insert one.  How do I set it to locate the line to repace it?  Thanks.